# replace text in form python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
state_dict = {'Alabama' :'AL'   ,'Montana': 'MT', 'Alaska'  :'AK', 'Nebraska':  'NE', 'Arizona':    'AZ',   'Nevada':   'NV', 'Arkansas':   'AR',   'New Hampshire':    'NH', 'California': 'CA',   'New Jersey':   'NJ', 'Colorado':   'CO',   'New Mexico':   'NM', 'Connecticut': 'CT',  'New York': 'NY', 'Delaware':   'DE',   'North Carolina':   'NC', 'Florida':    'FL',   'North Dakota': 'ND', 'Georgia':    'GA',   'Ohio': 'OH', 'Hawaii': 'HI',   'Oklahoma'  :'OK', 'Idaho': 'ID',   'Oregon':   'OR', 'Illinois':   'IL',   'Pennsylvania': 'PA', 'Indiana':    'IN',   'Rhode Island': 'RI', 'Iowa':   'IA',   'South Carolina':   'SC', 'Kansas'  :'KS',  'South Dakota': 'SD', 'Kentucky':   'KY',   'Tennessee':    'TN', 'Louisiana':  'LA',   'Texas':    'TX', 'Maine':  'ME',   'Utah': 'UT', 'Maryland':   'MD',   'Vermont':  'VT', 'Massachusetts':  'MA',   'Virginia': 'VA', 'Michigan':   'MI',   'Washington':   'WA', 'Minnesota':  'MN',   'West Virginia':    'WV', 'Mississippi':    'MS',   'Wisconsin':    'WI', 'Missouri':   'MO',   'Wyoming':  'WY'}

state_list_in_full = ['Alabama' ,'Montana', 'Alaska', 'Nebraska', 'Arizona',    'Nevada', 'Arkansas',   'New Hampshire', 'California',  'New Jersey', 'Colorado',   'New Mexico', 'Connecticut',    'New York', 'Delaware', 'North Carolina', 'Florida',    'North Dakota', 'Georgia',  'Ohio', 'Hawaii',   'Oklahoma', 'Idaho',    'Oregon', 'Illinois',   'Pennsylvania', 'Indiana',  'Rhode Island', 'Iowa', 'South Carolina', 'Kansas', 'South Dakota', 'Kentucky', 'Tennessee', 'Louisiana',   'Texas', 'Maine',   'Utah', 'Maryland', 'Vermont', 'Massachusetts', 'Virginia', 'Michigan', 'Washington', 'Minnesota',  'West Virginia', 'Mississippi', 'Wisconsin', 'Missouri',    'Wyoming']
```

I want to replace US state names full form form the `text` string to Abbreviated forms of which I had made the dictionary as written above.

```
text = 'Suite 202, Second Floor, 1717, Montana West Northern Avenue, Phoenix, Alaska Arizona - 85021'
```

Expected Output:

```
Suite 202, Second Floor, 1717, MT West Northern Avenue, Phoenix, AK AZ - 85021
```

Where

```
Montana is replaced by MT

Alaska is replaced AK

Arizona is replaced by AZ
```

I tried something with this

```
for tag in a:
    text = text.replace(old,new)

print text
```

I know the typical usage of str.replace in python but how to place dictionary key's value inplace of new & state string in old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. Simply loop over the dictionary and make replacements using the `replace` method. A convenient way to loop over the dictionary in this case is to use the `.items()` method, which returns `(key, value)` tuples that you can break apart to give better names to each item.

```
In [1]: text = 'Suite 202, Second Floor, 1717, Montana West Northern Avenue, Phoenix, Alaska Arizona - 85021'

In [2]: state_dict = {'Alaska': 'AK', 'Arizona': 'AZ'}

In [3]: for state, abbrev in state_dict.items():
   ...:     text = text.replace(state, abbrev)
   ...:

In [4]: text
Out[4]: 'Suite 202, Second Floor, 1717, Montana West Northern Avenue, Phoenix, AK AZ - 85021'
```

Note that this is rather simplistic. It will replace every occurrence of the state names, which may cause errors. (What if someone lives at `'123 Kentucky Ave'`?) You may want to break the address up into its constituent parts before attempting this replacement. The most common way to do this is to have the user enter it all separately for you, as addresses can take a massive amount of formats, and splitting them up programatically can be difficult or even impossible to do correctly, depending on how many inputs you have and the diversity of addresses on hand.

---

By splitting up the address, I mean that you appear to have something like this:

```
address = '123 Kentucky Ave, Louisville, Kentucky, 41304'
```

If you did the above replacement, you'd end up with an invalid address (`'123 KY Ave'`). To avoid this, I recommend taking your input differently to see if you can get something like this:

```
street_address = '123 Kentucky Ave'
city = 'Louisville'
state = 'Kentucky'
ZIP_code = '41304'
```

Then you'd only run the replacement on `state`, not the whole address at once. For multiple addresses, you could have a list of dicts like so:

```
addresses = [{
    'street_address': '123 Kentucky Ave',
    'city': 'Louisville',
    'state': 'Kentucky',
    'ZIP_code': '41304',
}, {
    'street_address': '123 Anytown Rd',
    'city': 'Anytown',
    'state': 'OH',
    'ZIP_code': '41839',
}]
```

Then your replacement might look something like:

```
for address in addresses:
    for state, abbrev in state_dict.items():
        address['state'] = address['state'].replace(state, abbrev)
```

Comment: if someone lives at '123 Kentucky Ave', then how could dictionary go wrong?

Comment: You'd end up with `'123 KY Ave'` which is no longer a correct address.

Comment: Ohh you mean state name can collide with other words in the address

Comment: this is really bad

Comment: That's why I recommend splitting the address into component parts instead of trying to operate on the whole string at once.

Comment: okay lets split the address, So how would '123', 'Kentucky','Ave' would solve this issue? Kentucky would still be replaced...right? sorry if i am sounding irritating

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer to reply because there's too much code to put in a comment (won't format correctly). One sec.

Comment: Hmm, but that's even more difficult to implement the separation of Street address, city , state, Country form a address string. I either had to use Google geocoding API. There is no programmable solution for this

Comment: Other possible try could be to run this replacer on second half of string or only next to Zipcode is present

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
state_dict = {'Alabama' :'AL'   ,'Montana': 'MT', 'Alaska'  :'AK', 'Nebraska':  'NE', 'Arizona':    'AZ',   'Nevada':   'NV', 'Arkansas':   'AR',   'New Hampshire':    'NH', 'California': 'CA',   'New Jersey':   'NJ', 'Colorado':   'CO',   'New Mexico':   'NM', 'Connecticut': 'CT',  'New York': 'NY', 'Delaware':   'DE',   'North Carolina':   'NC', 'Florida':    'FL',   'North Dakota': 'ND', 'Georgia':    'GA',   'Ohio': 'OH', 'Hawaii': 'HI',   'Oklahoma'  :'OK', 'Idaho': 'ID',   'Oregon':   'OR', 'Illinois':   'IL',   'Pennsylvania': 'PA', 'Indiana':    'IN',   'Rhode Island': 'RI', 'Iowa':   'IA',   'South Carolina':   'SC', 'Kansas'  :'KS',  'South Dakota': 'SD', 'Kentucky':   'KY',   'Tennessee':    'TN', 'Louisiana':  'LA',   'Texas':    'TX', 'Maine':  'ME',   'Utah': 'UT', 'Maryland':   'MD',   'Vermont':  'VT', 'Massachusetts':  'MA',   'Virginia': 'VA', 'Michigan':   'MI',   'Washington':   'WA', 'Minnesota':  'MN',   'West Virginia':    'WV', 'Mississippi':    'MS',   'Wisconsin':    'WI', 'Missouri':   'MO',   'Wyoming':  'WY'}

text = 'Suite 202, Second Floor, 1717, Montana West Northern Avenue, Phoenix, Alaska Arizona - 85021'

for full_name, abbreviation in zip(state_dict.keys(), state_dict.values()):
    text = text.replace(full_name, abbreviation)

print(text)
'Suite 202, Second Floor, 1717, MT West Northern Avenue, Phoenix, AK AZ - 85021'
```